Что посоветуете для работы с RTP?
Дискорд забанили и теперь появляется желание сделать что-то своё, просто как эксперимент и тренировку для себя.
Я уже могу сделать базовый чат с winsock tcpip и передачу файлов по ftp, но не стоит останавливаться и следуйщий шагом является передача голоса.
Я уже понял что голос передаётся благодаря VoIP и RTP. Что стоит почитать и какие библиотеки использовать что бы сделать передачу голоса.
В основном пишу на C++ и Python, но могу по быстрому за месяцок подтянуть Java
P.S. если можно то без Qt

Рекомендую поднять как вариант SIP. https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP_Tutorial https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/tree/master/pjsip-apps/src/pygui есть с чего начать. Кроме rtp нужно ещё освоить sdp и прикрутить какойто сигнальный механизм- а через библиотеку где всё есть - это проще. c++, python, java есть.
Рекомендую как вариант webrtc
https://aiortc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ есть примеры связи с браузером и безсерверная связь.
Вещание и стримы лучше делать через rtmp, а управление воспроизведением есть на rtsp.
И всё это добро выше использует rtp.
